# Set formula for defined range in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to apply a formula to an entire defined range as follows:

```
    Set Teens_2015 = Range("RM_2015").Offset(, -1)
        Worksheets(5).Teens_2015.Formula = "=SUM(AI2:AK2)"
```

Where RM_2015 is a named range in my workbook. I get the following error when I run this:

```
    Runtime error'438':
    Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Can someone clue me in as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: `Teens_2015` is not a valid method of the `Worksheets` object.  You can't chain variables like that.  Remove the Worksheets from in front of it so that it's just `Teens_2015.Formula = "=SUM(AI2:AK2)"`

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to fully qualify the range object and then use that, otherwise you create a conflict by trying to use a range from the active sheet as belonging to another sheet: presumably you want Teens_2015 to refer to sheet 5 rather than the active sheet.

```
Set Teens_2015 = Worksheets(5).Range("RM_2015").Offset(, -1)
Teens_2015.Formula = "=SUM(AI2:AK2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range("RM_2015").Offset(, -1).Formula = "=SUM(AI2:AK2)"`

Answer (score 0):

It's "Worksheets(5)" that doesn't support the "Teens_2015" method.  If you remove "Worksheets(5)" and just refer directly to the variable you set, it works fine:

```
Set Teens_2015 = Range("RM_2015").Offset(, -1)
Teens_2015.Formula = "=SUM(AI2:AK2)"
```